# Upload images using AWS S3 SDK v2 for iOS: Track progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading 15 photos to AWS S3 (v2) and I want to show the progress for each photo.

First, I created an AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest for each photo.

```c
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
// load uploadRequest atts...
uploadRequest.uploadProgress = ^(int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend) {
    int progress = (int)(totalBytesSent * 100.0 / totalBytesExpectedToSend);
    DDLogInfo(@"%d", progress);
}
```

Then I created a NSArray of BFTask

```c
BFTask *task = [self.s3transferManager upload:uploadRequest];
[tasks addObject:task];
```

Finally:

```c
[[BFTask taskForCompletionOfAllTasks:tasks] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

    if (task.error != nil) {           
        DDLogError(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
    } else {
        DDLogInfo(@"Complete!");
    }        
    return nil;        
}];
```

The problem I have is that the block associated with "uploadProgress" executes for the first 4 photos and then the rest of them are just uploaded but not tracking the progress.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems is a bug: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/91#issuecomment-69859140

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will help you but I attach my code for how I show progress of uploading to AWS S3 using AWS SDK v2. In my case I show the total progress for all files. I notice that you don't seem to be updating your progress on the main thread which could be the error in your code. Hope this helps.

```
    for (NSURL *myurl in self.myenum){
        AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
        uploadRequest.bucket = @"yourbucketname";
        uploadRequest.body = myurl;    
        self.fileSize = @([[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:myurl.path error:nil][NSFileSize] unsignedLongLongValue]);

        self.expectedToUpload = @(self.expectedToUpload.unsignedLongLongValue + fileSize.unsignedLongLongValue);
         __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

         uploadRequest.contentLength = self.fileSize;
         uploadRequest.uploadProgress = ^(int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend){
         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               @synchronized(weakSelf){
                        // NSLog(@"%@ => %llu %llu",myurl,totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend);
                        // NSLog(@"Progress => %f",(weakSelf.fileAlreadyUpload.unsignedLongLongValue*1.0/weakSelf.expectedToUpload.unsignedLongLongValue)*100);
                   weakSelf.fileAlreadyUpload = @(weakSelf.fileAlreadyUpload.unsignedLongLongValue + bytesSent);
                   weakSelf.myprogressbarController.progressbarView.progress = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong: (weakSelf.fileAlreadyUpload.unsignedLongLongValue/weakSelf.expectedToUpload.unsignedLongLongValue)*100];
                }
                self.myprogressbarController.progressbarView.progress = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: myprogress];
               [self.myprogressbarController.progressbarView setNeedsDisplay:YES]:
            });
```

I upload the files using a uploadcontroller:

```
-(void) uploadController{

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    NSMutableArray *tasks = [NSMutableArray new];
    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
    for (AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequestLocal in self.arrayOfUploadRequests objectAtIndex){
        [tasks addObject:[[transferManager upload:uploadRequestLocal] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            if (task.error != nil) {
                if( task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled
                   &&
                   task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused
                   )
                {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",StatusLabelFailed);
                    weakSelf.uploadFailure = @([weakSelf.uploadFailure intValue] + 1);
                }
            } else {
                weakSelf.uploadCount = @([weakSelf.uploadCount intValue] + 1);
                weakSelf.uploadSuccess = @([weakSelf.uploadSuccess intValue] + 1);

            }
            return nil;

        }]];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the code to be executed on main thread but it didn't fix the problem. Could you please share the code in where you make the upload? Maybe the problem is there. Are you using parallel or sequence upload?

Answer (score 1):

I combined in sequence and in parallel uploads in order to fix it. I think the new version of the SDK has a bug (tracking progress) when you upload more than 4 tasks in parallel, so I uploaded the photos in groups of 4 and execute the tasks in sequence.

Upload photos 1,2,3,4 then upload photos 5,6,7,8, then...

I reported an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/91